# Configure logrotate status file

Tags: linux, redhat, logrotate

I am trying to use logrotate to rotate my log files. However, we don't want to do that as root. However, if I execute it with some other job account it fails as its not able to edit or create file  /var/lib/logrotate.status. Is there a way to configure log rotate to use a different status file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried to use "-s" parameter? From manual:

```
   -s, --state <statefile>
          Tells logrotate to use an alternate state file.  This is  useful
          if  logrotate  is being run as a different user for various sets
          of log files.  The default state file is /var/lib/logrotate/sta-
          tus.
```